# Getting started

Tags: mining-hardware

I read some reviews and would like to try my hand at this Bitcoin thing.

I see that costly, dedicated hardware is the way to go. I have a dual XEON E5420 (http://goo.gl/Frco5X), 8Gb DDRII RAM sitting on a Intel S5000VSA motherboard. I have a 15K 146Gb SAS Drive available to load an OS.

1. Would I just waste effort and electricity getting this up and running.
2. What would the best OS be to load to maximize CPU power for mining the hashes?

Comment: Sorry, "costly, dedicated hardware" doesn't refer to nice CPUs, but to [ASIC](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asic)s. The latter are computer chips which can exclusively do mining. CPU mining has not been profitable for more than four years.

Comment: related: [Is CPU mining even worth it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/59/5406), [How much Bitcoin will I mine right now with hardware X?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118/5406), [When did the ASIC mining era begin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/40944/5406)